# JavaFX Alert on current screen

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I have a problem using the `Alert` class in order to make a popup when pressing a certain button, for example when trying to change a variable, a popup would show up asking "Are you sure you want to change that?" and you could click on "Yes" or "No". The problem appears in a multi-screen setup, specifically when the main application is not on the main screen. If you click on the button that triggers this `Alert`, then the popup will show up on the main screen, not on the current one. Is there a way to force it to show up on the current screen? Thank you.

This is an example of the popup:

**Popup Example**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
alert.initOwner(stage);
```

...before calling `show()` or `showAndWait()` on the alert, where `stage` is the stage you want the alert to appear over.